# Add field to Site Settings in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

this question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640187/add-a-mediapicker-to-the-general-site-settings) but it targets **Orchard CMS 1.8**, where `Site Settings` were redesigned.

I've implemented `HomeSettingsPart` to store my custom settings for *Home page*.

```
public class HomeSettingsPart : ContentPart { 
    public int NewsCount {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.NewsCount); }
        set { this.Store(x => x.NewsCount, value); }
    }

    public int MaterialsCount {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.MaterialsCount); }
        set { this.Store(x => x.MaterialsCount, value); }
    }

    public string WelcomeText {
        get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.WelcomeText); }
        set { this.Store(x => x.WelcomeText, value); }
    }

}
```

Also I've added a `handler` for this part:

```
public class HomeSettingsHandler : ContentHandler {

    public HomeSettingsHandler() {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<HomeSettingsPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(new TemplateFilterForPart<HomeSettingsPart>("HomeSettings", "Parts.HomeSettings", "HomePage"));
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context) {
        if (context.ContentItem.ContentType != "Site")
            return;
        base.GetItemMetadata(context);
        context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(new GroupInfo(T("HomePage")));
    }
}
```

Everything is like in [this tutorial](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings) and **this code works fine**.

Now I want to add an `MediaLibraryPickerField` to this  content part. I've added this field in *migrations* as usual and I see it in AdminUI *ContentManagement/Parts* section.

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("HomeSettingsPart", x => x
    .WithField("HomeSlider", y => y 
        .OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
        .WithDisplayName("...")
        .WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "true")
     )
 );
```

But, when I open my `Settings/HomeSettings` I see only 3 editors for my `HomeSettingsPart` and nothing is rendered for picker field. 
So, how do I add this field correctly?

thanks.

Comment: I'd question the usage of site settings to store a home slider in the first place: that's not a setting, it's content. This is a job for widgets, not site settings.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy good point. I was thinking about it too. But widgets usually  provide logic, not content managment, don't they?

Comment: Not at all: widgets are content items.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, yep, I've just read couple of articles about widgets, you're correct. Using them I can Edit widget and upload desired pictures. As for me, I think it's not trasparent for end-user, that user should go to widgets-edit and upload content there, it looks more like as configuration, not content management. I mean may be Orchard should separate widget managment (like placement and settings) and widget content. for now they are in one place, as I understand

Comment: Well, I understand you feel this way, but to my knowledge, nobody else has suggested that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this page in the documentation site : http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings

Comment: you can find this link my question text